# Need better performant XSLT

Tags: performance, xslt

### Input XML

```
<PayrollGroup xmlns="http://www.example.org">
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>1</EmpID>
      <Name>Jacob</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>Regular</HoursType>
      <Hours>80</Hours>
      <EarningsType></EarningsType>
      <Earnings></Earnings>
    </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>1</EmpID>
      <Name>Jacob</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType></HoursType>
      <Hours></Hours>
      <EarningsType>Regular</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>800.00</Earnings>
     </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>2</EmpID>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType></HoursType>
      <Hours></Hours>
      <EarningsType>Regular</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>1000.00</Earnings>
     </Payroll>
     <Payroll>
      <EmpID>3</EmpID>
      <Name>Augira</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>Other</HoursType>
      <Hours>12</Hours>
      <EarningsType></EarningsType>
      <Earnings></Earnings>
     </Payroll>
     <Payroll>
      <EmpID>4</EmpID>
      <Name>Satya</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>SMT</HoursType>
      <Hours>40</Hours>
      <EarningsType></EarningsType>
      <Earnings></Earnings>
     </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>4</EmpID>
      <Name>Satya</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType></HoursType>
      <Hours></Hours>
      <EarningsType>SMT</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>600.00</Earnings>
     </Payroll>
 </PayrollGroup>
```

### Output XML

```
<PayrollGroup xmlns="http://www.example.org">
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>1</EmpID>
      <Name>Jacob</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>Regular</HoursType>
      <Hours>80</Hours>
      <EarningsType>Regular</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>800.00</Earnings>
    </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>2</EmpID>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType></HoursType>
      <Hours></Hours>
      <EarningsType>Regular</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>1000.00</Earnings>
     </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>3</EmpID>
      <Name>Augira</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>Other</HoursType>
      <Hours>12</Hours>
      <EarningsType></EarningsType>
      <Earnings></Earnings>
    </Payroll>
    <Payroll>
      <EmpID>4</EmpID>
      <Name>Satya</Name>
      <WeekNumber>12</WeekNumber>
      <HoursType>SMT</HoursType>
      <Hours>40</Hours>
      <EarningsType>SMT</EarningsType>
      <Earnings>600.00</Earnings>
     </Payroll>
 </PayrollGroup>
```

**Problem Statement :** 
   Need an XSLT to transform from Input XML above to Output XML
   The actual sample of input XML is around 10 MB and I wrote a transformation that does looping on PayrollGroup twice which is of O(n2) order of n square. This is extremely getting bad for my server and is throwing out of memory exception.

Can someone provide a better performant XSLT.?

Edit:

The below are 2 XSLT's that I am using to achieve this one after the other

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:PayrollGroup>
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll">
        <xsl:variable name="empId" select="ns0:EmpID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="earningsType" select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
        <xsl:variable name="hoursType" select="ns0:HoursType"/>
        <ns0:Payroll>
          <ns0:EmpID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EmpID"/>
          </ns0:EmpID>
          <ns0:Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Name"/>
          </ns0:Name>
          <ns0:WeekNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:WeekNumber"/>
          </ns0:WeekNumber>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ns0:HoursType = '' and ns0:Hours ='' and ns0:EarningsType !='' and ns0:Earnings !='' ">
              <ns0:HoursType>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = $empId and ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:HoursType"/>
              </ns0:HoursType>
              <ns0:Hours>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = $empId and ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:Hours"/>
              </ns0:Hours>
              <ns0:EarningsType>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
              </ns0:EarningsType>
              <ns0:Earnings>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Earnings"/>
              </ns0:Earnings>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ns0:HoursType != '' and ns0:Hours !='' and ns0:EarningsType ='' and ns0:Earnings ='' ">
              <ns0:HoursType>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HoursType"/>
              </ns0:HoursType>
              <ns0:Hours>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Hours"/>
              </ns0:Hours>
              <ns0:EarningsType>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = $empId and ns0:EarningsType = $hoursType]/ns0:EarningsType"/>
              </ns0:EarningsType>
              <ns0:Earnings>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = $empId and ns0:EarningsType = $hoursType]/ns0:Earnings"/>
              </ns0:Earnings>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <ns0:HoursType>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HoursType"/>
              </ns0:HoursType>
              <ns0:Hours>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Hours"/>
              </ns0:Hours>
              <ns0:EarningsType>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
              </ns0:EarningsType>
              <ns0:Earnings>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Earnings"/>
              </ns0:Earnings>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </ns0:Payroll>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:PayrollGroup>
  </xsl:template>
```

After that the below XSLT to remove duplicates

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll">
    <xsl:if test="not(following::ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = current()/ns0:EmpID])">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you currently have, even if it is not performant? Also, can you explain the logic you are trying to implement. It looks like you are trying to group the `Payroll` elements by `EmpID`. (Although where does `Satya` come from in your output XML?) Thanks!

Comment: Tim C, I updated the question with the XSLT that I am currently using. Also Satya was missed in Input XML previously that I added now.

Comment: Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? This is a grouping issue, and the solution differs depending on what version you are using.

Comment: Either of them is fine. XSLT 2.0 is preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether you are using one or two separate XSLT stylesheets here. However, you only need one, and the way to remove duplicates in XSLT 2.0 is use `xsl:for-each-group`. So, instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll">
```

Do this...

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll" group-by="ns0:EmpID">
```

In addition to this, the following line (and similar ones) could affect performance:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll[ns0:EmpID = $empId and ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:HoursType"/>
```

This is because they would have to search the entire XML document for a match. As you are using `xsl:for-each-group` you can restrict the search to only the current group (i.e. `Payroll` elements with the same `EmpID`)

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-group()[ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:HoursType"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="Emps" match="ns0:Payroll" use="ns0:EmpID" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns0:PayrollGroup>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:PayrollGroup/ns0:Payroll" group-by="ns0:EmpID">
    <xsl:variable name="empId" select="ns0:EmpID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="earningsType" select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hoursType" select="ns0:HoursType"/>
    <ns0:Payroll>
      <ns0:EmpID>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EmpID"/>
      </ns0:EmpID>
      <ns0:Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Name"/>
      </ns0:Name>
      <ns0:WeekNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:WeekNumber"/>
      </ns0:WeekNumber>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ns0:HoursType = '' and ns0:Hours ='' and ns0:EarningsType !='' and ns0:Earnings !='' ">
          <ns0:HoursType>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:HoursType"/>
          </ns0:HoursType>
          <ns0:Hours>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[ns0:HoursType = $earningsType]/ns0:Hours"/>
          </ns0:Hours>
          <ns0:EarningsType>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
          </ns0:EarningsType>
          <ns0:Earnings>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Earnings"/>
          </ns0:Earnings>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ns0:HoursType != '' and ns0:Hours !='' and ns0:EarningsType ='' and ns0:Earnings ='' ">
          <ns0:HoursType>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HoursType"/>
          </ns0:HoursType>
          <ns0:Hours>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Hours"/>
          </ns0:Hours>
          <ns0:EarningsType>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[ns0:EarningsType = $hoursType]/ns0:EarningsType"/>
          </ns0:EarningsType>
          <ns0:Earnings>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[ns0:EarningsType = $hoursType]/ns0:Earnings"/>
          </ns0:Earnings>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <ns0:HoursType>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HoursType"/>
          </ns0:HoursType>
          <ns0:Hours>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Hours"/>
          </ns0:Hours>
          <ns0:EarningsType>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:EarningsType"/>
          </ns0:EarningsType>
          <ns0:Earnings>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Earnings"/>
          </ns0:Earnings>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </ns0:Payroll>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</ns0:PayrollGroup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I exactly did the same. Even with this XSLT with 10 MB Input XML and 8 GB of JVM heap, I am still running into GC Overhead Exceeded , Out Of Memory error. Is there a way to improve the logic further ?

Comment: 10MB isn't really that big these days. I can't really see how the XSLT in my answer would cause an issue, so I wonder if the problem lies elsewhere....

Comment: After I increased the transaction timeout setting to 1 hr in my server, I ran this again and it took 48 mins to get successful.